# How to bypass Subscription Key for single operation in the API in Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Is there a way to disable the subscription key requirement on a single operation in the API manager?

I saw this post from the 3 years ago stating it was not possible: [How to bypass Subscription Key for single endpoint in the API in Azure API Managment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67072834/how-to-bypass-subscription-key-for-single-endpoint-in-the-api-in-azure-api-manag)

I'm wondering if there is a way to hack the inbound policy of the operation to surpass the requirement while maintaining security on remaining operations.

Here are some of my attempts:

```
<inbound>
    <base />
    <check-header name="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" failed-check-httpcode="200" failed-check-error-message="Ignore subscription key" />
</inbound>
```

```
<inbound>
    <base />
    <!-- Set a variable to determine if the subscription key header is present -->
    <set-variable name="hasSubscriptionKey" value="@(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", string.Empty)))" />
    
    <!-- Use the variable in the condition -->
    <choose>
        <when condition="@((bool)context.Variables["hasSubscriptionKey"])">
            <!-- Proceed normally if the subscription key is present -->
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <!-- Optionally handle the case where no subscription key is provided -->
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
</inbound>
```

Comment: you could split your API in multiple APIs and group them into products. Theny ou would be able to only require api-key for specific product.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, It is still not feasible to remove the Subscription Key from a single operation in APIM.

Thanks **@Thomas** for the comment. You can create the separate APIs as per your operation and group them in a Product. You need to add the Subscription key in API level only.

API--> Settings

[image]

You can remove the Subscription key from the header before passing it to the backend using below policy.

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-header name="ocp-apim-subscription-key" exists-action="delete" />
    </inbound>
</policies>
```

But in this case, you need to pass `ocp-apim-subscription-key` in the header while making the request. This policy will remove the key before passing it to backend.